# Android custom floor map and pointer

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system

I am developing an Android app for indoor positioning. I need to display a floor map (which is a picture read from memory) and draw an updatable pointer at a given point (current position) over it.

Any suggestions or examples on how to do this? Is there a better option rather than reading a picture?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you have successfully managed to position the device in the room, just dynamically get the dimensions of the image and then linearly translate your room coordinates to pixel coordinates.